# Angular 7 injected service throws TypeError after refresh when attempting to call methods

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, components, ionic4

I have a component `DevicePage` that requests an instance of `ServiceAdapter` in its constructor, and then uses that `ServiceAdapter` to request information in `ngOnInit()`. `ServiceAdatper` ALSO requests an instance of `Service` to make http calls and then transform the response into the necessary objects for the `DevicePage`. My simplified code is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-device',
  templateUrl: './device.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device.page.scss'],
})
export class DevicePage implements OnInit {

  private device: Device;    // beacon used in the HTML template to display info

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private adapter: ServiceAdapter) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Grab the beacon details
    this.adapter
      .getDevice(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
      .subscribe(device=> this.device = device);
  }

}
```

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceAdapter {

    constructor(private service: Service) {
    }

    getDevice(id: string): Observable<Device> {
        this.service.getDevice(id).pipe(
            map(response => {
                return this.extractDevice(response.data).shift();
            })
        )
    }

    private extractDevice(devices: Device[]) {
        return devices.map(device => <Beacon> {
            id: device.identifier,
            name: device.shadow.name
        });
    }
}
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  getDevice(id): Observable<DevicesResponseV3> {
    return this.http.get<DevicesResponseV3>(URL_DEVICES)
      .pipe(catchError(err => this.handleError(err)));
  }

   private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Error response from ${error.url} ` +
        `Backend returned code ${error.status} ` +
        `body was: ${error.message}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

When I first arrive at this page from initially opening the app and navigating to it, everything works as expected. However, when I refresh the page, I get the following error:
`ERROR TypeError: "this.adapter.getDevice(...) is undefined"`. The service itself is not undefined, I am unsure what is happening.

The contents of my app.module.ts file:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'herald-client-webapp'),
    AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: At first glance, everything seems fine to me. Can you reproduce the same error with a minimal version of your app and share it via Stackblitz?

Comment: Yes working on it now.

Comment: In ngOnInit `this.estimote.getDevice` is used, but `estimote` is not declared. Another thing that I don't get it is that there is an `EstimoteService`, but is not used.
I know that's not your actual problem, but I can't find where the `this.adapter.getDevice()` is used.

Comment: Sorry that was some leftover code. I’ve updated it.

Answer (score 0):

did you refresh the page by save some code when ionic serve is runnig?

if so, don't worry it'll work when you publish the app,
set a debugger and look at :

```
getDevice(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
```

the id maybe is null.
you can also get param when entring the page:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.estimote
      .getDevice(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
      .subscribe(device=> this.device = device);
}
```